# Google Chrome Not Showing Image html5 canvas in Print Preview

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have some code to create function print canvas. Google Chrome is not showing in the print preview, but other browsers are working fine. How can I get it to work in Chrome also

```js
function print() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('LineWithLine');
  var imgcanvas = canvas.toDataURL();
  var myWindow = window.open();
  myWindow.document.write("<img src = '" + imgcanvas + "'/>");
  myWindow.document.close();
  myWindow.focus();
  myWindow.print();
  myWindow.close();
}
$('#Print').on('click', function() {
  print();
});
```

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/jz06qLhk/1/

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,that works really well